# Graph API version on old App IDs (Facebook Unity SDK 6.0.0)

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I recently found a weird behavior with the Facebook SDK for Unity (v6.0.0) where it would query FB using the old Graph API (1.0) if your app ID is created before April 30th 2014.

As I understand base on limited documentation about this behavior, the SDK will automatically enforce to the new 2.0 API after April 30th 2015. This is all good if assuming the API response format does not change. However, I noticed there is a change in the me/permissions listing query which gave very different response depending on the APP ID provided:

1. When using APP ID created **before** April 30th 2014, the response format is using Graph API 1.0's format.
2. When using APP ID created **AFTER** April 30th 2014, the response format is for 2.0

This is a very odd and confusing behavior. It means at the moment, even if I upgrade the Facebook SDK to the latest, it will always query through Graph API 1.0? How am I supposed to upgrade my game to support the new 2.0 API before the April 30th 2015 deadline?

As it is now, if I fix my code to parse the response data as described in the 2.0 doc, it will never work for my already released apps of pre April 30th 2014 and will only just break it.

So the question is, is there a way to force the SDK to use 2.0 API? IMHO, This whole auto API version selection base on APP ID thing feels retarded and pointless. Facebook should just enforce it such that new SDK always use new API. Us developers will know how to fix it ourselves and publish a new update for our users.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the version to be higher than the app version by passing the version as part of the graph API call, e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/**v2.0**/me/permissions

You can test this with the Graph Explorer tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
Try 'unversioned' in the dropdown and me/permissions as the edge - for a 1.0 app you get the old format, for a 2.x app you get the new format. Now switch the version dropdown to 2.x and repeat. Should both be on the 2.x format.

Comment: You can now also override the version in the developer dashboard for test users. Check out this guide https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/12/18/making-it-easier-to-upgrade-to-api-v2.x/